# error 0x80131623 appears when I closed UI

Tags: c#, error-handling, pinvoke

I'm trying to find the vendor id and the product id of a USB card. For this purpose, I use     setupapi.dll. When I closed my program I have 0x80131623 (2146232797) appears. I don't know how I can fix it.

My code is :

```
result = HidD_GetHidGuid(ref HidGuid);


         DeviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref HidGuid, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 18);


        do
        {
            SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA MyDeviceInterfaceData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
            MyDeviceInterfaceData.cbSize = 28;

            result = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(DeviceInfoSet, IntPtr.Zero, ref HidGuid, MemberIndex, ref MyDeviceInterfaceData);
            //int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (result != 0)
            {
                //SP_DEVINFO_DATA MyDeviceInfoData = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
                //MyDeviceInfoData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(MyDeviceInfoData);



                //Premier appel pour obtenir la taille du buffer
                result = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(DeviceInfoSet, ref MyDeviceInterfaceData, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out neededSize, IntPtr.Zero);
                //int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                int requiredSize = (int)neededSize;


                SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA MyDeviceInterfaceDetailData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA();
                if (IntPtr.Size == 8) // for 64 bit operating systems
                    MyDeviceInterfaceDetailData.cbSize = 8;
                else
                    MyDeviceInterfaceDetailData.cbSize = 4 + Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize; // for 32 bit systems


                 IntPtr detailDataBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(requiredSize);
                  Marshal.StructureToPtr(MyDeviceInterfaceDetailData, detailDataBuffer, true);


                  result = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(DeviceInfoSet, ref MyDeviceInterfaceData, detailDataBuffer, requiredSize, out neededSize, IntPtr.Zero);
                  int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                  //string instanceID = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(detailDataBuffer);
                  Marshal.PtrToStructure(detailDataBuffer, MyDeviceInterfaceDetailData);
                  if (MyDeviceInterfaceDetailData.DevicePath.IndexOf("vid_04fa&pid_9123") != -1)       
                  {

                      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(detailDataBuffer);
                      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(DeviceInfoSet);
                      return true;
                  }
                MemberIndex++;
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(detailDataBuffer);

            }
            else
            {
                //int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            if (MemberIndex>=16) { lastDevice = true; }


        } while (lastDevice == false);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(DeviceInfoSet);
        return false;


    }
```

I think the problem is caused by Marshaling.

Comment: Handle returned by SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces should be released by SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList. I don't see SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList in your code fragment, using Marshal.FreeHGlobal for this purpose is incorrect.

Comment: That's the error code for COR_E_FAILFAST, the equivalent of calling Environment.FailFast().  Which is certainly one way to quickly end a program.  The CLR can use it too when it finds its internal state corrupted.  That's all I can guess at.